# speed up styled component by removing duplication

Tags: css, styled-components

I have to do

```
const Flex = styled.div`
display: flex;
align-center: center
`
```

a lot, is there any way I can reduce this by making UI? is it common to have `Flex` in a common folder? or is there a UI library for styled-components? I don't want to use a very opinionated UI library like bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can always export your `Flex` component from a common styled components folder and use it elsewhere. You can also pass some props to it to make it even more flexible:

```ts
export const Flex = styled.div<{ align?: string }>`
  display: flex;
  align-items: ${({align}) => align ? align : center}
`
```

And use it like so:

```ts
import { Flex } from './styled-components';

<Flex align="start">...</Flex>
```

Comment: do you have any lib / util to recommend?

Comment: I'm not using any at the moment, I just created my own folder :)